# setState change unreliable in changing object properties

Tags: react-native, video, expo, state

I'm trying to make a custom play button appear when a video is paused. The play button disappears and reappears when it is clicked directly (expected behavior), but not when I use the video's "native controls" though the value of the corresponding state variable does change. What am I doing wrong?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { activateKeepAwake, deactivateKeepAwake } from 'expo-keep-awake';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Audio, Video } from 'expo-av';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export class VideoControl extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.playButton = React.createRef();
    console.log("props props props");
    this.video = null;
    this.state = {
      "vidPlaying": true,
      "playOpacity": 1,
      "playbackObject": null

    }
    
  }
      
  _handleVideoRef = component => {
    this.video = component; 
  }

  _playState = playStatus => {
    // console.log(playStatus["isPlaying"]);
    if (playStatus.isPlaying == true && this.state.vidPlaying == false) {
      console.log("playing is ");
      activateKeepAwake();
      this.setState({"vidPlaying": true});
      console.log(this.state.vidPlaying);
    }
    else if (playStatus.isPlaying == false && this.state.vidPlaying == true) {
      console.log("paused");
      deactivateKeepAwake();
      this.setState({"vidPlaying": false});
      console.log(this.state.vidPlaying);
    }
    // console.log(this.state.vidPlaying);
  }

  playVideo = async () => {
    if (this.video !== null) {
      var stat = await this.video.getStatusAsync();
      if (stat.isPlaying == true) {
        console.log("playing")
        this.video.pauseAsync(); 
      }
      else {
        console.log("not playing")
        if (stat.positionMillis == stat.playableDurationMillis) {
          this.video.replayAsync();
        }
        else {
          this.video.playAsync();
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  render(){
  return(
    <View>

        <Video
          source={{ uri: this.props.uri }}
          rate={1.0}
          volume={1.0}
          isMuted={false}
          resizeMode={Video.RESIZE_MODE_CONTAIN}
          useNativeControls={true}
          shouldPlay={false}
          isLooping={false}
          style={{ height: 400 }}
          ref={this._handleVideoRef}
          onPlaybackStatusUpdate={this._playState}
        />
        
        <View style={{ 
          alignSelf: "center",
          flex:1,
          flexDirection: "row",
          height: "100%", 
          width: "100%", 
          justifyContent: "space-around", 
          alignItems: "center", 
          flex: 1, 
          position: "absolute"}}>
          <TouchableOpacity 
            ref={this.playButton}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.4)',
              width: 80,
              height: 80,
              borderRadius:80,
              justifyContent: "space-around",
              opacity: this.state.vidPlaying? 1:0,
              alignItems: "center"
            }}
            underlayColor="#111" delayPressIn={0} delayPressOut={10} onPress={this.playVideo}>
            <Ionicons name="ios-play" 
                style={{
                    textShadowColor: '#333',
                    textShadowOffset: {width: -1, height: 1},
                    textShadowRadius: 10}} 
                size={54} 
                color="white" />
              
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
        <Text style={{flex: 1, fontSize: 30, position: "absolute"}}> Terst {this.state.vidPlaying? 1:0} </Text>

      </View>
  )
}
}
```

The console.log inside the _playState handler prints the right vidPlaying value as expected (though sometimes it switches rapidly). At the same time, even in expected behavior, somehow the value of vidPlaying being passed to the TouchableHighlight is really the opposite of what should be going. The button is visible when my test text shows 0, and vice versa. The text changes when the state changes, either from the touchablehighlight click or the nativecontrols play, but the touchablehighlight doesn't always.

Comment: state changes are asynchronous. to really check if the value has changed correctly pass your console log as a callback `this.setState({..}, () => console.log(this.state.vidPlaying))`

Comment: That might explain the rapid changes, but it always stabilizes to the expected value in both the text and the console.log? Is there something about the component refresh that only gets called once?